# JavaScript array values turned to undefined when not debugging in IE11

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer

I have written a very simple partition function in JavaScript:

```
Array.prototype.partition = function (size, step) {
    var out = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.length - size; i += step) {
        var tmp = this.slice(i, i + size);
        //two lines below were for quick debug
        //console.log(tmp);
        //console.log(out);
        out.push(tmp);
    }

    return out;
};
```

Example usage:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.partition(2, 1));
```

When running in latest Firefox it works like expected:

```
[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[7,8],[8,9],[9,10]]
```

I have big issues with it in IE11 though.
If I run that script without any breakpoints in the mentioned function, it seems like all values in the returned array are 'undefined':
[image: No-breakpoints]

If, however I set at least one breakpoint within the function (in IE debugger), and it pauses within the function on that point, everything seems fine:
[image: Breakpoints]

Very strange though that the outputs are at different stages. As you can see without breakpoints both logs are within the same "Navigation occurred" section (whatever that is). While when using breakpoints and debugging, they are in two separate ones.
Any idea what is going on here? Is it some IE bug? Thanks for your help.

---EDIT---
Just realized that despite the fact that these values are being logged in the console as undefined, they in fact are not, and still can be used elsewhere. Seems to me like a logging issue...

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in my local IE11, it works as expected. I created a test on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/xadoxoda/1/edit

Comment: if you stick it into a simple html file and run, you will see the same issue. the jsbin looks fine to me too.

Comment: To me the symptoms sound like some kind of race condition, as in something isn't defined until a few milliseconds after the calculation attempt.

Comment: Is `arr` in global scope?  If not, the arrays are probably garbage collected before you expand them in the console.  Chrome's console behaves similarly.

Comment: Arrays are in a script tag in the html file header, not sure if that counts as a global scope. That is what I thought as well, they are simply garbage collected b4 I expand. Especially that if I iterate through the produced (partitioned) array, and log each individual element, they are ok, but the array itself is still full of undefined.